# Typecasting int to char, then search array

Tags: c, arrays, string, casting, int

I have a problem with typecasting in C.

Let me explain my problem first: I have a 2-dimensional array of integers that is filled with numbers from 0-9 (its a sudoku and 0 means a empty space).

Then I have a second array and that is a 3-dimensional char array. It contains all the possible values for the empty spaces of my sudoku as a string "123456789". Now after I filled both of the 2 arrays (does work), I want to loop with 2 for loops over my int array and find all places where there is already a value from 1-9. I save that value in a temporary variable.

Then I want to loop over the char array and remove the value of the temporary variable from all lines and rows that are connected to the place where I found the value in the int array (like a real sudoku, every umber can only occur once in every line & row).

Well, to search a char array I need a char. But the temporary variable is an int so I have to typecast it and there is the problem.

```
for(j=0; j<9; j++){
    for(k=0; k<9; k++){
        if (grid[j][k] != 0){

            help_variable_remove_pv = grid[j][k];

            cast_number/*char*/ = (char) help_variable_remove_pv/*int*/;

            printf("%c", cast_number); 
            printf("\n%d", cast_number); 

        }
    }
}
```

I cast the int to a char. But when display it on the console to test it. I get a "smiley" when I print it as a char but it displays the actual number when I print as an integer. But I need the actual number in a char not in an int.

```
void sudoku_read(int sudoku[9][9])

int j, k;
char filename[100];

printf("Please enter file name: ");
scanf("%s", filename);

FILE *file1 = fopen(filename, "r");

for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
        fscanf(file1,"%d\t", &sudoku[j][k]);
    }
}    



fclose(file1);

void set_possible_values(char possible_values[9][9][10]){

int  j, k;
char string [] = "123456789";

for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(k=0;k<9;k++){
        memcpy(possible_values[j][k], string, 10);
    }
} 



void sudoku_solve(int grid[9][9])

 int j, k, a, b, i;
 int help_variable_remove_pv;
 char cast_number;

 char possible_values[9][9][10];
 char zero_string [] = "000000000";

 set_possible_values(possible_values);



for(j=0; j<9; j++){
    for(k=0; k<9; k++){
        if (grid[j][k] > 0){

            memcpy(possible_values[j][k], zero_string, 10);

        }   
    }
}    


for(j=0; j<9; j++){
    for(k=0; k<9; k++){
        if (grid[j][k] != 0){

            help_variable_remove_pv = grid[j][k];

            cast_number/*char*/ = (char) help_variable_remove_pv/*int*/;

            printf("%c", cast_number); /*Gives out a smiley*/
            printf("\n%d", cast_number);  /*Gives out the number*/




        }
    }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 

int n, j, k, i;

int board [9][9];

printf("How many Sudokus should be solved: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    sudoku_read(board);
    sudoku_solve(board);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: So if I understand the question correctly, the actual question is "how to convert an integer to a character?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
cast_number/*char*/ = (char) help_variable_remove_pv + '0'/*int*/;
```

instead of

```
cast_number/*char*/ = (char) help_variable_remove_pv/*int*/;
```

A character and an integer somewhat are different. This means that `'0'`(character 0) and integer 0 aren't equal. You'll have to add 48 (ASCII value of `'0'`) to 0 to get the integer value of `'0'`. See [The ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) for more information about characters and their integer equivalent.

Note that 48 and `'0'` are identical *integers*.

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain that `'0'` represents the integer value for the character, and leave ASCII out of your explanation... That way people won't get the idea that ASCII is a requirement, despite how common it is in this day and age (and probably the future), and get a big surprise when they do use something else (e.g. EBCDIC).

Answer (score 2):

A `char` variable is basically just like any other integer variable, but whose value is the encoding of the character. For the common [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) encoding the character `'A'` have the decimal value 65. So if you print `'A'` as a character you get the `A`, but if you print it as an integer you get the value `65`.

And if you look at the linked table, you will see that the values for the digits are `48` to `57`, all consecutive, meaning you can add `'0'` to any decimal digit to get its ASCII value, i.e. the character. So `'0' + 5` will result in the value `53` which when printed as a character is `'5'`.

Comment: For completeness' sake it might be worth pointing out that C requires this property of the encoding for the decimal digits. `'0' + 3` is always `'3'`. This is not guaranteed for the letters of the alphabet, only for the digits.